# Is there a way to use Entity Framework and Linq to order by a dynamic field?

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework, linq, tree

(Note: There may be a better word than "dynamic" to use in the title but I couldn't think of one.)

I have a database that contains several self-referencing tables. An example of one would be the following:

```
+----------+
| Category |
+----+-----+-+-----------+
| id | title | parent_id |
+----+-------+-----------+
```

where `parent_id` is a foreign key to `id` in the same table, so categories can be nested in (theoretically) infinite levels.

The following is sample data for that table:

```
Animal
 |- Fish
 |   |- Shark
 |   \- Trout
 \- Mammal
     |- Cat
     \- Dog
Plant
 |- Tree
 |   |- Fir
 |   \- Palm
 \- Vegetable
     |- Cabbage
     \- Lettuce
```

A .NET project that currently uses `SqlConnection` objects to execute queries on the database can render the above as "flat" strings, like this:

```
Animal
Animal > Fish
Animal > Fish > Shark
Animal > Fish > Trout
Animal > Mammal
Animal > Mammal > Cat
Animal > Mammal > Dog
Plant
Plant > Tree
Plant > Tree > Fir
Plant > Tree > Palm
Plant > Vegetable
Plant > Vegetable > Cabbage
Plant > Vegetable > Lettuce
```

It does this by using a recursive database function that returns the "full title" of a category by getting given its ID. The result of this function is used in both the query's `SELECT` list and its `ORDER BY` clause:

```
select Category.*, dbo.GetFullCategoryName(Category.id) as full_title
from Category
order by dbo.GetFullCategoryName(Category.id)
```

**What would be the best way to do the same using Entity Framework and Linq?**
The solution could still use a database function to get the full title string, if that would help.

I tried to emulate this by adding a `[NotMapped]` field to the Model class, which queries the DbSet and does the equivalent of the database function, but this field cannot then be used for ordering in a Linq query.

Of course I could still get an unordered list and then re-order this list using extra code that does use the field, but I'm wondering if there's a "cleaner" way to do the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do it using a view in the database.

The view in question has each category's ID as well as its full title, which it gets using the aforementioned function.

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[CategoryFullTitle]
AS
SELECT id, dbo.GetFullCategoryName(id) AS full_title
FROM dbo.Category
```

A separate class (CategoryFullTitle) is used in EF to map to that view, and the Category class includes one such object, using its ID as a foreign key.

```
[Table("CategoryFullTitle")] // The view's name
internal class CategoryFullTitle
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [Column("full_title")]
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

[Table("Category")]
internal class Category
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    /* ... */

    [ForeignKey(nameof(Id))]
    public virtual CategoryFullTitle FullTitle { get; set; }
}
```

Linq can order by "category.FullTitle.Text" and Category objects can then be used to add and update rows in the database, which would not be possible if a view was used *instead* of the table.